# Getting TypeError(): test_if_module_exists() when running nosetests

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

UPDATE: If i change

```
from scitools.std import *
```

to e.g.

```
from scitools.std import sqrt, zeros
```

everything works fine..

I'm trying to run nosestests -s myfile.py, but I'm getting this error all the time:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Test if modulename can be imported, and if not, write
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/util.py", line 613, in newfunc
    return func(*arg, **kw)
TypeError: test_if_module_exists() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

PROGRAM:

```
from scitools.std import *
import nose.tools as nt

def test_test():

    diff = 1E-6
    nt.assert_almost_equal(diff, 0, delta=1E-5)

def main():
    print __name__

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm running Nose 1.3.0. Have searched all over the internet for solutions, can't find a thing!

Thanks guys!

Comment: It's difficult to say without the code of `myfile.py`. Please provide.

Comment: Your code does not match the error message.  Please provide matching code and error message.

Comment: I ran into this with a function named `get_test_text(a,b=None)`. Changing the function signature to `get_something_text(a,b=None)` resolved it. Nose thinks your function named `test_if_module_exists` is a test to run. You could also change your .noserc to ignore that file or filename pattern

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using a wildcard import... *Dont use wildcards!*

Basically when you say

```
from scitools.stf import *
```

You are also importing everything from:

- scitools.easyviz
- scitools.basics

The way that nose works is that it looks for all the functions named `test_` in your module. That includes every function you wrote and every function that you imported. This is called [Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). So if there is a function you do not want nose to try to run, *Dont import it*. When you were using a a wildcard import, *you are importing everything*, which is most of why wildcards are not a good idea to use. Just import the functions you need, eg

```
from scitools.std import sqrt, zeros
```